# Python Django media url not working after setting DEBUG = True

Tags: python, django, debugging, media, media-url

As stated in topic, my Django site media url is returning 404 after trying to access it. Everything was working flawless until I wanted to end the development process and set

```
DEBUG = True
```

in settings.py to have the site finished once and for all. When I change DEBUG back to

```
DEBUG = False
```

it works fine once again. I have no idea what's the problem, any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is by design: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

> If you use django.contrib.staticfiles as explained above, runserver will do this automatically when DEBUG is set to True.

That being said, you can use the following workaround by modifying your `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
  + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Note that this is highly inefficient and not encouraged for production use. You should normally configure your web server (apache, nginx, etc) to serve your static and media content.

Comment: Do I set it in the app urls.py or the site urls.py?

Comment: It would be the site's `urls.py`. Remember to add the `import` statements too.